# Can we use shrink rays to go back in time?

Tags: time-travel, quantum

I researched muons, the Higgs boson, and quarks, and at least one of them can be used for a shrink ray. I'm not asking if we could build a shrink ray, I know it is possible to build one. I'm asking if we could use a shrink ray to enter the quantum realm and come out without knowing the date. Nanoparticles could be used to form into a robot after it exited the quantum realm because a robot would probably become nonfunctional after entering the quantum realm if Nano-technology is invented by then.

So is my Theory correct? I spent half a week searching for answers and researching about this, I'm asking the question here in case there are any blank spots.

*The original question was closed on physics SE, I thought it would be appropriate here, physics SE basically said I got inspired by a movie and got all my info from sci-fi*

Comment: May I see the research that you mentioned?

Comment: if you're serious about this, it's all nonsense; if it's for your fiction, then you make the rules. it would be better form not to copy too much from the MCU.

Comment: Just to be clear, this site is for people who are developing **imaginary** worlds, who have come up with part of their idea but are stuck on a detail, or how to make it plausible or consistent. The concepts of "shrink rays" and "the quantum realm" are definitely fictional, but since you don't do much more than name them, the answer to "will they allow time travel?" is really "yes, if you, the author, want them to". See the [help] for more tips on what makes a good question here.

Comment: "I know it's possible to build one (shrink ray)" - could you expand on this? Are you saying - in your fictional world, it's possible?

Comment: Handwaving a bunch of stuff, if was possible to shrink someone to a size so small that they were the size of a Planck, where (in theory) there was no way to measure motion at all, it seems plausible that the concept of the passage of time would be meaningless but rather than providing the ability to "travel in time" one would instead be (hypothetically) in perfect stasis and if un-shrunk in the future (even far future) would not have perceived the passage of time. Note, there would be no way to unshrink oneself in the future as at Planck scale "waiting" has no meaning.

Comment: As retro style handwavium for a blockbuster movie - yeah good stuff, as real world - no. WB aspect seems to be lacking in the q, however. Handwaviums on their own usually have low chances to be improved, and this one is way too far from reality to make any suggestions based on current science.

Comment: humans wouldn't be shrunk, I talked about robots

Answer (score 4):

## No

Or, perhaps more accurately, *humanity knows of no such ability should a human being be magically shrunk such that all the particles in the human body are now smaller than the elements in the quantum realm itself, making the quarks, muons, etc. that make up the human body smaller than their counter parts around the shrunken person. Further, while there may be mathematical exercises investigating how quantum-level interactions affect (or are affected by) time, there is no evidence whatsoever that time travel is possible or even plausible in any way, shape, or form.*

What the Marvel Comic Universe did was classic worldbuilding! They took just enough science to make something look credible, then added their own world rules that allowed for something cool to happen *in their universe.*

But you're not asking about the MCU (which would be off-topic anyway, we don't allow questions about 3rd-party or commercial worlds). Nor do you seem to be asking about a fictional world of your own creation (which would be on-topic...). You appear to be asking about *real life,* which is technically only allowed here *when asking in the context of building a fictional world of your own creation.*

But, to conclude...

***No, your theory is not correct.***

BTW, "nanoparticles" is a term that describes particles in the range of 10<sup>-9</sup> meters. But it's most frequently a *technobabble* term that means *a super-small object that doesn't follow the rules of physics as we know it.* Quantum particles are ever so much smaller than nanoparticles, so no, you can't use nanoparticles to float around in the quantum realm. That's the fiction of the MCU.

*BTW, if it were actually possible to shrink anything down to the quantum realm, it would be more likely to create a whomping good bomb than it would permit time travel. But that would violate the Laws of Thermodynamics. Damn you MCU!*

Answer (score 0):

You may have stumbled upon some.article about quantum gravity, a field in quantum research that has produced some equations that unexpectedly lack a time variable where we would expect one (e.g.: the Wheeler-DeWitt equation,.which assigns quantum states to the universe).

This has absolutely zero to do with time travel. If you look at works on this you may find discussions on the direction of the arrow of time and enthropy, but not a hint of anything that would allow you to violate causality.

Also there is no quantum realm to enter or exit. You just got inspired by a movie and got all your info from scifi, and secondhand via the movie on top of that, which turns ok scifi into bad scifi. In real life macroscopic objects are subject to the same physics as subatomic particles. It just so happens that defining the wave function for something with so many particles such as a brick or a person is prohibitively complex, but we do have it. "Shrinking" something would not change this.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't shrink-ray people

You are talking Superhero-comics here. And we got a physics professor that studies Superheroes. He is [James Kakalios from the University of Minnesota](https://youtu.be/YXd5Y0RXLb0). In his [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Physics_of_Superheroes) is one chapter about Hank Pym, aka the real Ant Man/Giant Man/Yellowjacket/Ultron's Dad/many more. And he made an interview, that among other things, [looks at MCU Ant Man](https://youtu.be/DuFyGHgGIKg?t=371). Yes, the guy who **shrinks**. In both sources he notes that Marvel technobables it to be "changing the spacing between the atoms". that is an impossibility.

Yet, if you apply hard physics, and somehow were able to adjust Planck's Constant to adjust the size of atoms, you could technically shrink bodies. However, there is no way to just adjust Planck's Constant for a small area. It's always the same for everywhere. According to the current understanding, it's $h=6.626176 \times 10^{-34} \frac {\text m^2 \text{ kg}} {\text{s}}$. [We are pretty sure that it underlies no variation over time.](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/ParticleAndNuclear/constants.html)

**Without handwavium that adjusts $h$ for just one body, you can't shrink ray people.**

As a direct result, you can't use shrinking for time travel: You can't shrink, so you can't time travel. And shrinking doesn't enable time travel anyway.

Comment: I am saying, your premise that by shrinking you can time travel fails at step 1: You can't shrink.